# CMake can't find X11

Tags: xorg, cmake

I'm trying to compile Minetest 0.4.10 on Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS with CMake, but I get this error:

```
andrew@rasts-tv:~$ cmake \Minetest-0.4.10
-- *** Will build version 0.4.10 ***
-- IRRLICHT_SOURCE_DIR = 
-- IRRLICHT_INCLUDE_DIR = IRRLICHT_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND
-- IRRLICHT_LIBRARY = IRRLICHT_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
-- Could NOT find IRRLICHT (missing:  IRRLICHT_LIBRARY IRRLICHT_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- CURL_INCLUDE_DIR = CURL_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND
-- CURL_LIBRARY = CURL_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
-- CURL_DLL = 
-- GetText disabled
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindX11.cmake:411 (MESSAGE):
  Could not find X11
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/CMakeLists.txt:147 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I installed LXDE (Lightweight X11 Desktop Environment), but it still shows the same error. What should I do?

This is the error message I got after installing the x11 header files:

```
andrew@rasts-tv:~$ cmake \Minetest-0.4.10
-- *** Will build version 0.4.10 ***
-- IRRLICHT_SOURCE_DIR = 
-- IRRLICHT_INCLUDE_DIR = IRRLICHT_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND
-- IRRLICHT_LIBRARY = IRRLICHT_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
-- Could NOT find IRRLICHT (missing:  IRRLICHT_LIBRARY IRRLICHT_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- CURL_INCLUDE_DIR = CURL_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND
-- CURL_LIBRARY = CURL_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
-- CURL_DLL = 
-- GetText disabled
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:91(MESSAGE):
Could NOT find OpenGL (missing: OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:252(_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindOpenGL.cmake:153 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
src/CMakeLists.txt:148 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Answer (score 18):

[LXDE](http://lxde.org/lxde) and [X11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) are not quite the same thing. You probably need the X11 header files. Try installing `libx11-dev`:

```
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev
```

Comment: Now cmake can't find OpenGL.

Comment: @user249312 Either edit the question to add the new error message, or post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

try running the command

```
sudo apt install xorg-dev
```